# requestFeature ActionBar doesn't add ActionBar

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to try and add an ActionBar to my Activity which uses Theme.Holo.NoActionBar

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.show();
```

I get an exception at the last line saying actionBar is null.  I'm targetting API 19 but running on API 18.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to use actionbar in an activity, then why are you using a them with NoActionBar?

Comment: The above code is in a conditional, most times I don't want an action bar but for this condition I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a theme that enables the use of the `ActionBar` in your activity (such as one of the Theme.Holo... theme versions that DO include activation settings of the ActionBar, as an example) and control whether the action bar is shown or not, by alternating the use of `ActionBar.Show()`/`Hide()` methods.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing but it doesn't look as good because the actionbar may show for a split second before I'm able to make the hide() call.